# Black screen on different network & wifi in flutter webrtc

Tags: flutter, dart, webrtc, videocall, flutter-webrtc

**Call: Listen to the sender / Receiver of the call if both are connected to different wifi networks,
tests are performed with mobile data and the result is the same.
When making a call connected to the same wifi network it is possible to listen to the sender and receiver during the call.
After connection showing a black screen in the video call**

**Make a call with a different network or wifi and the call will connect but show a black screen for another user.**

**It should not show the black screen in case of the same wifi and internet.**

**Platform information**

- **Plugin version**:
  `flutter_webrtc:`
       `git: https://github.com/flutter-webrtc/flutter-webrtc`
- **OS**: Android / iOS
- **OS version**: All

[image: on mobile network]